# "Provider Kzu.NuGetReferences.GraphProvider failed to initialize" Visual Studio 2015 error

Tags: visual-studio

After opening VS project, I have some error in "Task List".

> Failure has occured while loading a type.
>
> Provider Kzu.NuGetReferences.GraphProvider failed to initialize.
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

What wrong with VS 2015?

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you open an issue in the corresponding [github project](https://github.com/kzu/NuGetReferences) if the behaviour persists. A stack trace of the exception would help, too.